# How to create a progress text from my log in bash

Tags: bash, redirect, logging

I have a script that output all information to a log and print only when using my special PrintAndLog function.
I'm trying to add a dynamically status line that changes according to mylog last line.

how can i achieve this without adding code to each function? if possible at all.

#myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mylog=/tmp/my.log
exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2
exec 1>$mylog
exec 2>>$mylog

function PrintAndLog(){
echo $@ >&3
}

function RunList(){
for file in `ls /dir1/` ;do
    echo $file
    sleep 1
done
}

function InstallPackge(){
    yum install -y $@
}


PrintAndLog "Listing tmp folder."
RunList

PrintAndLog "Installing httpd."
InstallPackge "httpd"

PrintAndLog "Done"
```

The output should be something like this. i don't know how to illustrate this here but the first and second output should overwrite them self as the script progress.

```
#first output#
#Listing tmp folder.
#dynamically changing each time with the last line from mylog

#second output#
#Listing tmp folder.
#Installing httpd.
#dynamically changing each time with the last line from mylog
#Done
```

Comment: you comment is not in place. i actually don't know how to achieve that and my thinking is this is exactly the place that can help me.

Comment: yes, you're right. Not sure now why I left that msg (I have a cold. and I have deleted it). What you are looking to achieve will take some effort. Is it really that important? If eels to me like over-optimization. And of course  wiping out what files have already been processed from your display leaves you open to questioning "did file X really get processed?" and then having to go consult the logfile to see what happened. If you *really* need this then look for info on ncurses, which allows you to move the text cursor to X.Y positions. I know I've seen Qs here before about that. Good luck.